# Ckeditor shows extra space at the beginning and end of the p tags

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor for my small web project, but when I edit a content or create a new content, it automatically add white space after the opening of p tag and the text, when I remove the space and save the content it works but when I edit again, it add the space again, how do I remove it. I think the space between opening of p tag and the text should not matter, but it shows spaces while I retrieve those content from database and it mess up with my design. How do I solve this?

Here is the image for what I am trying to say:

[image]

Comment: haven't done anything weird with ck? as it doesn't happen to me.

Comment: same here. looks like this is somehow the default...

Comment: see http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=18067 and other threads on the issue. I think I'm using an older unaffected version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's just a setting: This is from an oldish resource, but I think it still applies, depending on the version you are using probably:

There seem to be settings for adding breaks and indents (your problem I guess) for opening a `p` tag:

```
this.dataProcessor.writer.setRules( 'p',
                    {
                        indent : false,
                        breakBeforeOpen : true,
                        breakAfterOpen : false,
                        breakBeforeClose : false,
                        breakAfterClose : true
                    });
```

Source : http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=18067  (but there are quite some other mentions of this problem to be found on google)

Comment: Did you read the topic I linked? You use it on the place you instantiate your editor.