# How to work with new line immediately after <p> tag from ck editor?

Tags: php, mysql, ckeditor

My question is related with a previous post,

[Ckeditor shows extra space at the beginning and end of the p tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992094/ckeditor-shows-extra-space-at-the-beginning-and-end-of-the-p-tags)

I have already a huge number of entries in my database, which has the same next line problem.
Now I could fix the issue in the CK editor. But the affected former entries are still there. The issue has came when I tried to parse the content using JSON. Next line causes some problems there.
My Options are : 
1. update the whole DB entries.
2. Handle with code where ever it is printing.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your database seems to be *huge*, I would follow this approach:

1. Fix it in the client code when it is going to be printed.
2. When you get that right, change the code so it also updates the database.
3. When you get that right, use that code to update the whole database by chunks (using crons or some other kind of scheduled tasks*).
4. Wait.
5. ???
6. Profit.

*: Or just dedicate some server time per request to do that. Or do it online, it is a good [excuse for slacking](http://xkcd.com/303/).

---

Ah, yes, the habitual recommendations. Develop using a copy and make back ups. C'mon you know that stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply.
Fortunately I understood what causes the line breaks. It's none other than " \r\n " (thanks for the post : [Replacing \r\n with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449580/replacing-r-n-with-php))

I exported the table and found out the issue. then replaced in the  dumb itself and imported back.

This bug ate my head badly and spoiled my weekend too!

Comment: So your database wasn't that *huge* :P Good to know it is solved, you can accept your own answer.